# How can I animate components to slide in [direction]?

Tags: angular

I'm making a personal website, where the different sections (i.e. Home, About, Portfolio, Contact) are actually components.

When I click on the section link (i.e. Contact), instead of simply redirecting to the component, I would like the existing component to `:exit` with `@slide` and the new component to `:enter` with `@slide`. The caveat is, I want any intermediate components to do the same thing. For example:

1. User starts at "Home" but clicks on "Contact".
2. Home `:leave`
3. About `:enter`, About `:leave`
4. Portfolio `:enter`, Portfolio `:leave`
5. Contact `:enter`

The components should slide either to the left or to the right depending on current `pageIndex` and destination `pageIndex`.

I'm aware there are jQuery and Angular API's for carousels but it'd be so much cooler to just code it myself. It's also not quite a traditional carousel. Am I asking for too much?

The problem with my current strategy is that the intermediate components are not getting animated. Using `console.log(componentRef)` inside `loadComponent()` shows that the intermediate components are getting created, and I ultimately do reach the right page, which `:enter`'s with animation. I'm also using a simple fade animation for testing because I'm having trouble with the slide animations as well.

[-- My current strategy --]:

```
    panels: PanelItem[]; 
    pageIndex = 0;
    @ViewChild(PanelDirective, {static: true}) panelHost: PanelDirective;

    loadComponent(index) {

        let panelItem = this.panels[index];

        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(panelItem.component);
        let viewContainerRef = this.panelHost.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();

        let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        console.log(componentRef);
      }

    changePanel(pageNum) {
        let dest = pageNum;
        let diff = dest-this.pageIndex;
        let curr = this.pageIndex;

        if(diff > 0) {
            for(let i=curr+1; i<dest+1; i++) {
                this.loadComponent(i);
            }
        }
        else if(diff < 0) {
            for (let i=curr-1; i>dest-1; i--) {
                this.loadComponent(i);
            }
        }

        this.pageIndex = pageNum;
        console.log(this.pageIndex);
      }
```

Animation:

```
export let fade = trigger('fade', [
    state('void', style({opacity:0})),
    state('*', style({})),
    transition(':enter, :leave', [
        animate(6000)
    ]),
]);
```

Comment: *"Am I asking for too much?"* - no, but you are making the conscious decision to re-invent the wheel here by not using the angular animation framework.

Comment: You're right. The reason there probably isn't a well-known way to do this is because it's A) so complex that Angular made it's own API; and/or B) there's a simple elegant way to accomplish this with CSS properties. I'm going to go explore.

Comment: Best bet may be to have css classes which reference and index `in--1``in--2` etc that you can then switch elements to via javascript. then let the initial css animation run against it to position them.

Comment: Are you lookin for routing animation? https://angular.io/guide/route-animations

Comment: @Eliseo I was just looking at that. But it takes about 20 lines of code just to animate between two pages...I have four total. Also I don’t think it’ll solve the problem of animating the intermediate pages.

Comment: Sungmin, you can use ":increment" and ":decrement". Well, the animation has 70 lines of code, but then, only change the router adding the line `data: { animation: '#' } ` (# is a number) you animate all the pages, see the answer

Comment: I used an increment/decrement helper function in the component .ts. I guess I could’ve use the animation increment/decrement functionality directly as well. But the key was definitely Router Animations. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as animation `:increment` and `:decrement`. Yes has a bit of code. Imagine you has in a .ts the animation

```
export const slideInAnimation =
    trigger('routeAnimations', [

        transition(':increment', [
            style({ position: 'relative' }),
            query(':enter, :leave', [
                style({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    width: '100%'
                })
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':enter', [
                style({ left: '100%' })
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
            group([
                query(':leave', [
                    animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '-100%' }))
                ], { optional: true }),
                query(':enter', [
                    animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '0%' }))
                ], { optional: true })
            ]),
            query(':enter', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
        ]),
        transition(':decrement', [
            style({ position: 'relative' }),
            query(':enter, :leave', [
                style({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    width: '100%'
                })
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':enter', [
                style({ left: '-100%' })
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
            group([
                query(':leave', [
                    animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '100%' }))
                ], { optional: true }),
                query(':enter', [
                    animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '0%' }))
                ], { optional: true })
            ]),
            query(':enter', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
        ])

    ]);
```

if you write in your main.app.html

```
<div [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And prepateOutlet

```
prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }
```

Your routes only need add as data "animation", some like

```
{ path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component, data: { animation: '1' } },
{ path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component, data: { animation: '2' } },
{ path: 'Page3', component: Page3Component, data: { animation: '3' } },
{ path: 'Page4', component: Page4Component, data: { animation: '4' } },
```

I [forked the stackblitz of angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ol2jno?file=src/app/app.module.ts)